# Ray interactor can't select a 3d Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am using the "player" asset from the Steam VR plug-in. I have added a Ray Interractor to the left and right hand child nodes of the player but I can't seem to select 3d Objects. XRI-Default-input-Actions asset is added to the XR-Controller (action-based) component of the Ray interactor (I deleted this component from the parent nodes). I also Added the Input Action Manager to the player node (parent node) and attached the XRI-default-input assets to it.

I just want to point at a 3d object and play a simple sound when I click on it.

I have setup the sounds and configured the Ray interactor so that it shows a reticle when hovering on the objects. Clicking on them does not seem to work tho...